# C# tag property doesn't work with my query

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

Using c# and sqlite

I'm trying to get my EduInstitCoutnrytxt1 textbox to update when I click on the datagridview, change the value and then click the update button. I was recommended to use the update query below but when I run it, the error I get is 'SQL logic error near "then": syntax error'. Pretty damn vague.

```
 private void Editbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //edits by name so cant change name
 {
    string txtQuery21 = "update EducationProfile set P3InstituteCountry = (case EpID when " + EduInstitCountrytxt1.Tag + " then '" + EduInstitCountrytxt1.Text + "' when " + EduInstitCountrytxt2.Tag + " then '" + EduInstitCountrytxt2.Text + "' when " + EduInstitCountrytxt3.Tag + " then '" + EduInstitCountrytxt3.Text + "' when " + EduInstitCountrytxt4.Tag + " then '" + EduInstitCountrytxt4.Text + "' end) ";

    ExecuteQuery(txtQuery21);
```

Then I found out that maybe the tag is null which would cause this error to appear. So I set the tags in the dgv click event to empty instead of null so by default it should be empty.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   EduInstitCountrytxt1.Tag = "";
   EduInstitCountrytxt2.Tag = "";
   EduInstitCountrytxt3.Tag = "";
   EduInstitCountrytxt4.Tag = "";
               ...
   string CommandTextedu = "select ep.P3ID, ep.P3InstituteCountry, ep.P3From, ep.P3To, ep.P3Qualifications, ep.P3FTPT, ep.EPID from JADB A left join EducationProfile ep on a.P1ID = ep.P3ID where a.P1ID = " + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
   DBedu = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandTextedu, sql_con);
   DTedu.Clear();
   DBedu.Fill(DTedu);

   int j = 1;
   foreach (DataRow dr in DTedu.Rows)
        {
            switch (j)
            {
                case 1:
                    EduInstitCountrytxt1.Tag = dr[6].ToString();
                    EduFromProfdateTimePicker1.Tag = dr[6].ToString();
                    EduToProfdateTimePicker1.Tag = dr[6].ToString();
                    EduQualificationstxt1.Tag = dr[6].ToString();
                    EduFTPTProfCB1.Tag = dr[6].ToString();

                    EduInstitCountrytxt1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                    EduFromProfdateTimePicker1.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                    EduToProfdateTimePicker1.Text = dr[3].ToString();
                    EduQualificationstxt1.Text = dr[4].ToString();
                    EduFTPTProfCB1.Text = dr[5].ToString();
                    break;
//more cases
            }
            j++;
        }
```

But it is still getting the same error. I tried checking if the EduInstitCountrytxt1.Tag was null and, using messagebox, the EduInstitCountrytxt1.Tag was null before I clicked on the dgv but had a value after I clicked on the dgv which was how I imagined it should work. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Never ever ever concatenate input to create SQL. There's a good chance that this is the main issue; please look at how to use SQL parameters, or use a tool like Dapper which makes parameterization insanely issue. A **very bad** "fix" (air quotes intentional) here might be to use quotes around the tag, but .... that's a really really bad idea, and the code you show is actively harmful.

Comment: Still don't really understand. From what I saw from google, I pretty much only used these kind of queries and never the ones I saw that you recommended so it's pretty much new to me.

Comment: if (wherever you were looking) didn't discuss parameterized queries, then (wherever you were looking) is a pretty bad source of information. Showing exactly how to do this *with your existing code* is kinda awkward, because: there's absolutely no need to use data-adapters, data-tables, etc here - and they are hurting you. Can I simply refer you to the Dapper home page which has  a few handy examples of simple parameterized data access? https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Comment: I'll try and go from here. Thanks!